# Int64 to Int on Otree survey

Tags: python, pycharm, integer, otree

I'm trying to host an Otree survey but I keep getting an error directed at this line of code that says "relevant_index should be set to int, not int64."

I have tried to use  a.astype(int)  but I'm still getting the error... can someone help me?

```
def set_treatment_vars(self):
        # Set the Answers of the Social Group
        if self.treatment == 'IND':
            self.A1 = 4
            self.A2 = 4
            self.A3 = 1
            self.A4 = 2
            self.A5 = 2
        elif self.treatment == 'COM':
            self.A1 = 3
            self.A2 = 3
            self.A3 = 3
            self.A4 = 3
            self.A5 = 3
        # Determine the Payoff Relevant Question and Answer
        self.relevant_index = np.random.choice(range(0, 5, 1))
        self.relevant_question = Constants.questions[self.relevant_index]
        answers = [self.A1, self.A2, self.A3, self.A4, self.A5]
        self.correct_answer = answers[self.relevant_index]
```